# Pass Claims between two ASP.NET 3.5 web sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, wif, claims-based-identity

I have two ASP.NET 3.5 web sites that I need to pass a claim from one site to the other site.

On one site I login and I can see the claim like the following:

```
var claimIdentity = (Context.User.Identity as Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.IClaimsIdentity);
claimIdentity.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Manager"));
```

But on the other site, I do not see the claim being passed.
I am using forms authentication between the sites and the machine key is the seom on both sites.
Login / auth cookie is being passed fine between the sites but I just don't see the claim being passed.

I did open fiddler and can see the auth cookie being passed but I don't see anything that looks like a claim being passed in the header or body.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ADFS as your IDP?

The most probable cause is that the claims rules for the two RP (the two ASP.NET 3.5 web sites) are not the same.

You should have SSO OOTB between the sites so if you are using IE and it's setup for IWA, it should be seamless.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Half of what you have listed above is foreign to me but I will look into each of the parts to see if I can answer what you have listed. I am not using ADFS. Basically I am trying to convert the old forms authentication I currently have into claims manually for each response.